# How to pass schema type: Object's key rules

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2, simpl-schema

I am trying to understand how to validate, an object using Meteor-Collection2. I can better explain in the code below:

```js
// This is the object structure to validate
// const obj = {
//   name: 'Test',
//   active: true,
// }

Test.schemaObj = {
  someOtherName: {
    type: String, // Not the same as obj variable
  },
  testType: {
    type: Object,
    // The goal is to define rules for validation for 
    // things that this will contain.
  },
  // Inside the object: {
  //     type: String,
  //     required: true,
  //},
  // Inside the object: {
  //     type: Boolean,
  //     required: true,
  //},
};
```

I understand that ***required*** is automatically set to true when not defined.

My purpose is to basically list all the keys that the object must have and their validation rules. I know how an array of object works, I am just not sure what the syntax is for object validation.

I went through the documentation and stack-overflow, but I was not able to find it anywhere online explicitly showing the syntax.

I am sure that I am missing something basic however, being new to this I was hoping that someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood which you want to validate the `testType` object. Then there are two ways:

1. You can add the blackbox: true, this will allow that object have any structure;
2. You need to define each property of object, like this:

```
Test.schemaObj = {
  someOtherName: {
    type: String, // Not the same as obj variable
  },
  testType: {
    type: Object,
    // The goal is to define rules for validation for 
    // things that this will contain.
  },
  "testType.attribute1": {
       type: String,
       required: true,
  },
  "testType.attribute2": {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
  },
};
```